# Input data from file from directory where filename updates each month

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this, but if it already exists, please share with me. I'm trying input a file that where the file ending is ambiguous within a directory. For example the directory would be 'ThisPC\Desktop\Folder' and I'm looking for file 'SomeData_April2021'. I need it to search for the term 'SomeData' within the folder, as the ending is updated for each month. There are also other files in the folder, so I can't just specify the directory and have it upload everything.

Hopefully this is clear! If not, I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions in the input step? I don't have access to a pentaho installation right now, but at least the text file input allows regex patterns.

Comment: I did but I couldn't get it to work. I don't think I had the syntax down correct and was struggling to figure it out. I'm relatively new to the program.

Comment: it's probably the best way to solve this, but regular expressions take some getting used to, yes. https://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to type (?i).+SomeData.*.* into the wildcard expression field